# what environment does `eval` execute in? (scheme)

Tags: scheme

I have the following `myFunc` function, the body of which is just an `eval` statement.
Could anyone tell me why `eval` is NOT seeing `a`?

Or a broader question would be, **where** do the arguments to `eval` get evaluated?

```
(define myFunc
  (lambda (a)
    (eval 'a)))

(myFunc 1)       ; <<<< this causes undefined var error, WHY? 

; define a var named a in the global
(define a 2)

(myFunc 2)      ; <<<<< this returns 2, WHY?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not need to use `eval` until you are a few years into your Scheme career.  By that I mean, many beginners incorrectly believe that `eval` is needed but it generally is not.

For your example, `eval` takes an optional second argument which is the `environment`.  If you don't provide the second argument, then the default is `(interaction-environment)`.  So, your `myFunc` defines a local variable `a` (the argument to `lambda`) and returns the value for `a` in the interaction environment.

The first time you invoke `(myFunc 1)` there is no `a` in the interaction environment.  Then you add `a`, bound to `2`, so the next time you invoke `(myFunc <anynumber>)` you get `a` in the interaction environment, which is `2`

Your definition for `myFunc` is not idiomatic.  If you really want a function that returns the value of a defined variable use:

```
(define myFunc
  (lambda (ignore)
    a))

> (define a 2)
> (myFunc 1234567)
2
> (set! a 10)
> (myFunc -9876)
10
```

Comment: Well, I'm not using `eval` *because I need to*. I'm actually just trying to get some inspiration from its behaviour as I'm designing a similar function (for some other language). So back to the question, is it fair to say that the binding of vars inside `eval` is dynamic?